# Problems with function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the alert for sheet already exist to work, however, I am lost.
Is the function not defined correct or?

```
 Public Sub CopySheets()

    Do

        shName = InputBox("Please enter name of new project", "New Project")

        If shName <> "" Then

        shExists = SheetExists(shName) 'Check for existing sheet name
        If Not shExists Then
        Worksheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)


        Else

        MsgBox "Project Name:" & Space(1) & shName & " already exists", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Deter"
        End If
        End If
    Loop Until Not shExists Or shName = ""
End Sub

Private Function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String, _
        Optional ByVal wb As Workbook)

        If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        SheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(sheetName) Is Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the type of the function. It must be `boolean`

```
    Private Function 

    SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String, _
        Optional ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean

        If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        SheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(sheetName) Is Nothing

    End Function
```

The issue with your code is that in case the sheet does not exist the line `SheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(sheetName) Is Nothing` will raise an error and `SheetExists` will keep its default value which is empty as the default data type of a function without defining the data type is `variant`. If you define the data type as `boolean` the default value will be `False`.

IMHO this code is clearer though longer

```
Private Function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String, _
    Optional ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error GoTo EH
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
    SheetExists = True

    Exit Function

EH:
    SheetExists = False

End Function
```

Comment: thoroughly explained, once again! Thanks a lot Storax. Have a great weekend.